# How is it possible to cast an interface to a class?

Tags: java, class, interface, groovy, casting

I have an **interface** *Class* object provided as a method parameter, and I also have a *Object* instance of the **object** being casted.

Task: To cast the object as if I would do the interface = object thing but manually using Class.cast() method.

And the star of the show:

```
def readObject(type, path) {
        Object obj
        // Prevent playing with NPE
        if (groovyClassLoader == null)
            groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader())

        // The final quest begins
        try {
            Class groovyClass = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(new File(path))

// at this point: type ins an instance of Class which is an interface
// to which I need to assign the obj instance

// groovyClass is an instance of Class 
// out of which I need to get object and eventually cast it to type
// so something like:
//            groovyClass = groovyClass.cast(type)
//            obj = groovyClass.newInstance()
// or
//            obj = groovyClass.newInstance()
//            obj = groovyClass.cast(type)



            obj = groovyClass.newInstance()
            obj = type.cast(obj)

        } catch (ex){
            //TODO:IO and obj creation exception should be logged
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return obj
    }
```

This is a mighty warior quest for survival with mage casting and I'm starting to feal that my mission is out of mighty land possibilities XD

Comment: `Class` is a class, not an interface. Perhaps you could clear this up by posting some code? :-) Also, what does this have to do with Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an interface.  You must first define a class that *implements* the interface and then create an instance of that class.  You can then pass this object as an argument to any method that accepts a parameter of the interface type.

Comment: Don't forget, you can use a map as an implementation of an Interface in Groovy, ie: `def endlessStreamOfOnes = [ hasNext:{ true }, next:{ 1 } ] as Iterator`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have an instance to an interface. Interface is just like a template. The concrete classes that implement the interface can have their own instances. Suppose I have the following:

```
public interface IExample {
  public void foo();
}

class Example implements IExample {
  public void foo() {
    // do something
  }
}

class MyMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IExample iExample;
    Example example = new Example();

    iExample = example; // Polymorphism :)

    // IExample iExample = new IExample();  -- is wrong
  }
}
```

In the above example, the object "example" can be casted to IExample (Polymorphism) but you cannot have memory allotted for the IExample interface since it does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that after cleared all the redundant comments in my code :D but too late)

Comment: Thanks ok. Good that you got the answer :)

Comment: I think you mean "implement" the interface rather than "inherit" from it.